# While doing breadth first search, does it matter when you visit the node?

Tags: java, graph, tree, breadth-first-search

I've written the following BFS for a tree in Java:

```
public class Node
{
    public int value;
    public ArrayList<Node> myChildren = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public Node(int v)
    {
        value = v;
    }
}

public Node breadthFirstSearch(Node root, int value)
{
    if(root == null) return null;
    Queue<Node> nodesToVisit = new LinkedList<Node>();
    nodesToVisit.add(root);
    while(nodesToVisit.size() > 0)
    {
        Node currentNode = nodesToVisit.remove();
        if(currentNode.value == value) return currentNode;
        nodesToVisit.addAll(currentNode.myChildren);
    }

    return null;
}
```

My question is, does it matter (in terms of runtime complexity or some other factor) when I "visit" the node `if(currentNode.value == value)`.  I could either visit the node after I've popped it off the queue, or before I put it on the queue.

Comment: I think this is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you visit the node as soon as you encounter it you're weighting your search even more to the 'left' (first child first) than it already inherently is.

Comment: Your `while` loop is better restated as `do ... while (!nodesToVisit.isEmpty())`. Of course it's never empty at the beginning of the loop, so why check for that impossible condition?

Comment: @seh I do it with a normal while loop because I feel that it increases readability of the code and evaluating the condition one extra time won't make any noticiable impact (only a few extra machine instructions)....However, I understand the point that you're making

Comment: I believe you, but there's a different kind of readability at stake: the reader needing to understand why guard conditions are in place, reasonably expecting that the guarded-against conditions might arise. If it seems that those conditions *can't* arise, then your program is over-constrained and borders on logical inconsistency. A different way to write your loop is to not bother adding the root node to the queue, and process it specially in advance. Instead you added it to the queue to avoid restating part of the loop body. That's fine, but don't do extra *work* to avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't matter (much).

You're basically talking about the order of these two lines:

```
if (currentNode.value == value) return currentNode;
nodesToVisit.addAll(currentNode.myChildren);
```

For performance and code clarity, returning early is always a good thing, so I would leave your code as it is.

If you reversed the order of these lines, you would incur the extra cost of the call to `addAll()`, which would however be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Does it matter? It depends on what you are doing.

If there is more than one node in the tree which meets your search criteria, then visiting parent before children, rather than children before parent, could change which one is returned by the search. Will that actually happen? It depends on the details of your application.

The big-O complexity will be the same either way. Depending on the characteristics of the trees and searches, more operations may be required one way or the other. (For example, if 50% of the searches are for the value which is stored in the root node, your code will run faster by visiting the parent nodes first.)

When a search "fails" (the value is nowhere to be found in the tree), the number of operations performed will be the same regardless of which order you visit nodes in.